# regex matching whole with a few criteria

Tags: regex

(I want to match the whole line, the purpose is this, in python, I will list all the files in a directory, then I want to pick those file urls based on certain keywords, ie 'qwert2asdf' and 'windows'):

My current regex:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_.\-\\]*(qwert2asdf)[a-zA-Z0-9_.\-\\]*(windows)[a-zA-Z0-9_.\-\\]*
```

matches line #4 which is what I need

```
4\\abc123-smb.ccabc.com\nfs\site\disks\.abcdefghigk.1234\abcdfff\day.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815\nnn-pppp\ass_bss_sw_qwert2asdf_evih_iii_ass_2401_system.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815.windows.tar.gz
```

question 1.is there a better way so I don't have to repeat [a-zA-Z0-9_.-\]*

question 2. how do I make the match so that it ignores the order of 'qwert2asdf' and 'windows', that is if 'windows' happen before 'qwert2asdf' and it'll still match?

```
1\\abc123-smb.ccabc.com\nfs\site\disks\.abcdefghigk.1234\abcdfff\day.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815\nnn-pppp\css_boxt_pkg_isys.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815.linux.tar.gz
2\\abc123-smb.ccabc.com\nfs\site\disks\.abcdefghigk.1234\abcdfff\day.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815\nnn-pppp\bbb_pkg_all_systems.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815.tar.gz
3\\abc123-smb.ccabc.com\nfs\site\disks\.abcdefghigk.1234\abcdfff\day.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815\nnn-pppp\ass_bss_sw_qwert2asdf_evih_iii_ass_2401_system.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815.linux.tar.gz
4\\abc123-smb.ccabc.com\nfs\site\disks\.abcdefghigk.1234\abcdfff\day.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815\nnn-pppp\ass_bss_sw_qwert2asdf_evih_iii_ass_2401_system.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815.windows.tar.gz
5\\abc123-smb.ccabc.com\nfs\site\disks\.abcdefghigk.1234\abcdfff\day.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815\nnn-pppp\ass_bss_sw_qwert2asdf_evih_iii_ass_2401_system.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815_vp.tar.gz
6\\abc123-smb.ccabc.com\nfs\site\disks\.abcdefghigk.1234\abcdfff\day.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815\nnn-pppp\ass_bss_sw_evih_iii_ass_2401_system.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815.linux.tar.gz
7\\abc123-smb.ccabc.com\nfs\site\disks\.abcdefghigk.1234\abcdfff\day.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815\nnn-pppp\ass_bss_sw_evih_iii_ass_2401_system.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815.windows.tar.gz
8\\abc123-smb.ccabc.com\nfs\site\disks\.abcdefghigk.1234\abcdfff\day.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815\nnn-pppp\ass_bss_sw_evih_iii_ass_2401_system.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815_vp.tar.gz
9\\abc123-smb.ccabc.com\nfs\site\disks\.abcdefghigk.1234\abcdfff\day.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815\nnn-pppp\ass_bss_sw_evih_iii_ass_system.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815.tar.gz
10\\abc123-smb.ccabc.com\nfs\site\disks\.abcdefghigk.1234\abcdfff\day.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815\nnn-pppp\doc_pkg_evih_iii_ass_system.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815.tar.gz
11\\abc123-smb.ccabc.com\nfs\site\disks\.abcdefghigk.1234\abcdfff\day.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815\nnn-pppp\ass_bss_sw_evih_iii_ass_2400_system.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815.linux.tar.gz
12\\abc123-smb.ccabc.com\nfs\site\disks\.abcdefghigk.1234\abcdfff\day.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815\nnn-pppp\ass_bss_sw_evih_iii_ass_2400_system.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815.windows.tar.gz
13\\abc123-smb.ccabc.com\nfs\site\disks\.abcdefghigk.1234\abcdfff\day.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815\nnn-pppp\ass_bss_sw_evih_iii_ass_2400_system.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815_vp.tar.gz
14\\abc123-smb.ccabc.com\nfs\site\disks\.abcdefghigk.1234\abcdfff\day.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815\nnn-pppp\css_pkg_css_skm_cgdsg0_system.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815.tar.gz
15\\abc123-smb.ccabc.com\nfs\site\disks\.abcdefghigk.1234\abcdfff\day.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815\nnn-pppp\css_pkg_css_skm_asdfgt_system.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815.tar.gz
16\\abc123-smb.ccabc.com\nfs\site\disks\.abcdefghigk.1234\abcdfff\day.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815\nnn-pppp\ass_bss_sw_boxtppc_evih_iii_ass_2401_system.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815.linux.tar.gz
17\\abc123-smb.ccabc.com\nfs\site\disks\.abcdefghigk.1234\abcdfff\day.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815\nnn-pppp\ass_bss_sw_boxtppc_evih_iii_ass_2401_system.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815.windows.tar.gz
18\\abc123-smb.ccabc.com\nfs\site\disks\.abcdefghigk.1234\abcdfff\day.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815\nnn-pppp\ass_bss_sw_boxtppc_evih_iii_ass_2401_system.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815_vp.tar.gz
19\\abc123-smb.ccabc.com\nfs\site\disks\.abcdefghigk.1234\abcdfff\day.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815\nnn-pppp\ia_css_2.1.3.0.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815.linux.tar.gz
20\\abc123-smb.ccabc.com\nfs\site\disks\.abcdefghigk.1234\abcdfff\day.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815\nnn-pppp\ia_css_2.1.3.0.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815.windows.tar.gz
21\\abc123-smb.ccabc.com\nfs\site\disks\.abcdefghigk.1234\abcdfff\day.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815\nnn-pppp\doc_pkg_ia_css_2.1.3.0.abcdefg_urururur_20140701_1815.tar.gz
```

Comment: I don't really understand what are you asking. Could you edit your question adding what is you want that a RE matches?

Comment: You haven't supplied enough information for a complete answer.  For example, I would suggest this expression to match line 4: `qwert2asdf.*windows`, but I expect that does not completely solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Positive Lookahead** here.

```
^(?=.*qwert2asdf)(?=.*windows)[\w\\.-]*$
```

**Explanation**:

```
^                # the beginning of the string
(?=              # look ahead to see if there is:
  .*             #   any character except \n (0 or more times)
  qwert2asdf     #   'qwert2asdf'
)                # end of look-ahead
(?=              # look ahead to see if there is:
  .*             #   any character except \n (0 or more times)
  windows        #   'windows'
)                # end of look-ahead
[\w\\.-]*        # any character of: word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _), 
                 #  '\\', '.', '-' (0 or more times)
$                # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uF9rD2/1)

Comment: And so wrong.  It matches many strings that the OP's pattern does not, and fails to match many strings that the OP's pattern does.

Comment: is there a way to ignore the order of "windows" and "qwert2asdf",

Comment: @hwnd could you answer question #2, please?

Comment: @user97662 This will ignore the order of both.

Comment: The lookahead approach is nice for matching strings that contain both substrings regardless of order, but the given pattern matches some strings the OP's pattern doesn't.  For example, it matches "qwert2asdf<>windows".

Comment: @JohnBollinger I fixed it to the OP's needs.

Comment: Nice clean solution, +1

Answer (score 0):

You did not say which regex flavor you are using (POSIX, Perl, Java, ...), but I am unaware of any that has a way to write a pattern that matches the same set of strings as yours without repeating the character class as yours does.

You might be tempted to look at back references, but they do not do what you want.

Depending on the host language, however, you might be able to reduce duplication by putting the text of the character class into a variable, and interpolating the variable into your regular expression at each of the three points.

Matching regardless of the order of the 'qwert2asdf' and 'windows' substrings is messier, but it can be done.  Here's one way that should work in pretty much any regex engine, modulo any metacharacter (non-)escaping that might need to be performed:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_.\-\\]*((qwert2asdf)[a-zA-Z0-9_.\-\\]*(windows)|(windows)[a-zA-Z0-9_.\-\\]*(qwert2asdf))[a-zA-Z0-9_.\-\\]*
```

A regex engine that supports zero-width lookbehind assertions would provide other alternatives, but I don't think any would come out shorter.

Comment: it's for python use, but I use Notepad++ find function to test.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
(.*?)windows(.*)
```